# lost Window Apache MySQL and PHP homepage

Tags: wamp

i recently deleted wamp server homepage from www folder permanently and now i want to access it to add a database in phpmyadmin.it was not present at recycle bin too! So please help me out in accessing it

Comment: Reinstall wamp ...

Comment: that was a good idea which even i could think.but i wholeheartedly appreciate the effort and time u spent for answering my question

Answer (score 1):

hey guys i finally got a solution which was simpler than we thought.i just got a copy of that webpage from my friend and pasted it in it's specific directory(i.e;www of wamp)hope this helps